# Cannot login Horizon Dashboard after using conjure-up NovaKVM Charm deployment

Tags: openstack, dashboard, juju

I have deployed my OpenStack using conjure-up NovaKVM juju charm on Ubuntu 18.04. My deployment has fully done according to conjure-up of juju status:

JUJU Status

[image]

However, with the following credential, I still cannot log in:

Horizon Login Page

[image]

Anything can I do to reset the password or get me in?

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the default password is different. Source `openrc` file, which you can find in the directory you run `conjure-up` from. And then see what are the values of environment variables. You should find your password there.

```
source openrc
env | grep OS_
```